# Why is including implementation for a friend function that uses template parameters inside of a template class without a template declaration compile?

Tags: c++, syntax, compilation, friend-function, template-function

Given the following code.

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
class Foo 
{
public:
    Foo(const T& value = T());

    friend Foo<T> operator+ (const Foo<T>& lhs, const Foo<T>& rhs)
    {
    // ...
    }
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& o, const Foo<T>& x)
    {
    // ...
    }
private:
    T value_;
};
```

The compiler has no trouble compiling both friend functions which have template parameters without having the following syntax

```
template <typename T>
friend Foo<T> operator+ (const Foo<T>& lhs, const Foo<T>& rhs)
```

or

```
friend Foo<T> operator+ <>(const Foo<T>& lhs, const Foo<T>& rhs)
```

or

```
friend Foo<T> operator+ <T>(const Foo<T>& lhs, const Foo<T>& rhs)
```

because they have been defined by their implementation inside the template class itself.

How can the compiler compile these friend functions with their template parameters without including a template declaration? Why is just having their implementation inside of the class enough?

I learned about this concept from [here](http://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#template-friends) under the section on ***"Why do I get linker errors when I use template friends?"***

Comment: Your code produces a separate non-templated function in the enclosing namespace for each instantiation. Here's a [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend#Template_friend_operators) on `friend`.

Comment: I don't follow sorry.

Comment: When you define it inline, the friend functions are not templates. The compiler generates them with the `Foo` classes it generates.

Comment: Your comment stating that the friend functions in the code above are not templates seems to contradict the link I posted in the section **"Why do I get linker errors when I use template friends?"** In the link it shows how to declare the friend functions as templates and gives the code above as an alternative to explicitly declaring them as templates. Could you elaborate on this and maybe explain what the code in the link may be doing differently than just explicitly declaring the friend functions as templates? I believe I'm missing something crucial which is causing my confusion on the topic.

Comment: Yes, this is an alternative. The other method uses free function templates. This method effectively uses free functions that are not templates. Both work to solve that problem. As the two are distinct solutions, any contradiction must remain local to that solution.

Comment: Therefore, I'm confused because I don't understand why this code works when the friend function is not a template. The friend function uses a parameter that is a template in it's implementation. So I guess the real question is, why is the implementation all that is needed for a friend function that uses template parameters inside of a template class?

Comment: All it does (that's relevant) is shift the generation of functions from when the function template gets instantiated to when the class template gets instantiated. When you have a template, one entire version is created for each different set of types you use with it. Since the function is generated when the class template is instantiated, it no longer uses the class's template parameter. If you use `Foo<int>`, even without using `operator+`, you generate a free `Foo<int> operator+ (const Foo<int>& lhs, const Foo<int>& rhs)`. No more templates at that point (`Foo<int>` is a regular type).

Comment: I understand the logic now. Thank you for the explanation. This is also convenient in terms of efficiency because both methods seem to take just as long. So, I don't have to worry about which way I should declare and define my friend functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two options, with and without `template<class T>`, do slightly different things.

When you introduce a `friend` function that way, you introduce it within the enclosing namespace in a way that is only reachable via ADL (argument dependent lookup).

The `template<class T>` introduces a function template, and the one without introduces an actual function.

So this:

```
template<class T>
struct foo {
  friend void bar(foo<T>){}
};
```

means that when `foo<int>` exists, a function `bar(foo<int>)` is created.  Then `foo<double>` creates `bar(foo<double>)`.

Each of these `bar`s are not `template` functions.  They are eaxh a function with a fixed signature, a new overload, imilar to if you wrote

```
void bar(foo<char>){}
```

right after `foo`.  The exception is that the `friend bar` can only be found via ADL, which changes how conflicts and overload resolution works.

Now this:

```
template<class T>
struct foo {
  template <typename X>
  friend void bar(foo<X>){}
};
```

creates a `template` `bar` for each instance of `foo`.  These do not conflict, because they are only found via ADL.  And the only one that can be found is the one where the `T` matches the `X` (in this case -- with more arguments it could differ).

It is rarely a good idea to do the `template` version, in my experience.

Comment: "When you introduce a `friend` function that way," Which way are you referring to and are both ways using argument dependent look-up? It sounds like your saying both methods use argument dependent look-up while at the same time saying 1 method uses argument dependent look-up. I assume you mean my code example above uses argument dependent look-up and the template function method does not. Also, why is it rarely a good idea to do the temple function method?

Comment: @wander one is a function the other a template function (a way of writing functions, but not itself a function until instantiated).  Both used ADL to be found.  Why one tends to be more useful is almost opinion/a long answer; in my experience, using a template with no payoff adds quirks and complexity.  For a concrete problem, the template friend case of ambinary operator requires both args to be template pattern matched: the friend case requires one of the type, the other can be implicitly converted to.